# Redirect from site.com to www.site.com?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IIS 6 - Setting up 301 redirect for non-www to www for SEO](https://serverfault.com/questions/66708/iis-6-setting-up-301-redirect-for-non-www-to-www-for-seo)

What would be the best way of achieving a redirect from, lets say site.com to www.site.com on a windows server? I have access to the dns server also, if anything could be done there to help it along.

I know you could do it by code (asp.net, php etc on your site) but i am wondering if it is possible only using iis and/or dns setup?

I see alot of sites using it these days, so was beginning to wonder :-) Also if you enter "site.com/thispage.html?1=2" it should redirect to "www.site.com/thispage.html?1=2"

Answer (score 2):

This has been [asked](https://serverfault.com/questions/85986/301-iis-redirect) and [answered](https://serverfault.com/questions/66708/iis-6-setting-up-301-redirect-for-non-www-to-www-for-seo) [repeatedly](https://serverfault.com/questions/88030/redirect-to-domain-without-www).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

```
http://www.xoc.net/works/tips/domain.asp
```

for Details :

```
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/41c238b2-1188-488f-bf2d-464383b1bb08.mspx?mfr=true
```